# Multiple states, same action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two counters, `COUNTER_1` and `COUNTER_2`. So I have created multiple reducers to handle them.

```
export default (state = 0, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
 case "INCREMENT_1":
   return state + 1;
 case "DECREMENT_1":
   return state - 1;
 default:
   return state;
 }
};
```

This is for `COUNTER_1` and similarly for `COUNTER_2` I have created

```
export default (state = 0, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case "INCREMENT_2":
   return state + 1;
  case "DECREMENT_2":
   return state - 1;
  default:
   return state;
 }
};
```

Now I have created an action creator for them that goes like

```
export function increment(counterNumber) {
 let stateSelector = counterNumber === 1 ? "INCREMENT_1": "INCREMENT_2"
 return {
  type: stateSelector 
 };
}
```

Is it fine to have the same `action creator` as illustrated in the above example for multiple reducers. I might have additional features for `COUNTER_1` which might not be there for `COUNTER_2` somewhere down the line. But the basic featuers for both would be `INCREMENT` and `DECREMENT`.

This is so that I can later add features to both counters independently while keeping the basic functionality same. Maybe add `INCREMENT_BY_TWO` just for `COUNTER_1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same reducer for the different counter.

```
function createCounterWithNamedType(counterName = '') {
    return function counter(state = 0, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case `INCREMENT_${counterName}`:
                return state + 1;
            case `DECREMENT_${counterName}`:
                return state - 1;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counterA : createCounterWithNamedType('A'),
    counterB : createCounterWithNamedType('B'),
    counterC : createCounterWithNamedType('C'),
});

store.dispatch({type : 'INCREMENT_B'});
console.log(store.getState());
// {counterA : 0, counterB : 1, counterC : 0const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counterA : createCounterWithNamedType('A'),
    counterB : createCounterWithNamedType('B'),
    counterC : createCounterWithNamedType('C'),
});

store.dispatch({type : 'INCREMENT_B'});
console.log(store.getState());
// {counterA : 0, counterB : 1, counterC : 0}}
```

Comment: So how would I separate concerns like when I want to add features to `COUNTER_A` which I do not want in `COUNTER_B`?

Comment: You can use reducer composition with `combineReducers`. This is a good implem,  `createCounter` should return the corresponding actionCreators though (imo).

Comment: @illiteratewriter, If you want to create counter have different properties then we can implement logic using `Higher Order Functions`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your state should contain your both counters:

```
export default (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
       case 'INCREMENT':
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.counter]: {
                     ...state[action.counter],
                     value: state[action.counter].value + 1
                }
            };

        case 'DECREMENT':
             return {
                ...state,
                [action.counter]: {
                     ...state[action.counter],
                     value: state[action.counter].value - 1
                }
            };
        default:
             return state;
     }
};

export function increment(counterNumber) {
   return {
       type: 'INCREMENT',
       counter: counterNumber
   };
}

export function decrement(counterNumber) {
   return {
       type: 'DECREMENT',
       counter: counterNumber
   };
}
```

Later you can access the counter value, or any other counter data like:

```
 this.state[counterNumber].value
```

Of course, the default state would be:

```
{
    1: {
        value: 0,
        someOtherProperty: false
    },
    2: {
        value: 0,
        someOtherProperty: true
    },
}
```